# Clientbank pytch iOS integration

Tags: ios, pytch-sdk

I am trying to integrate **Clickbank's Pytch** framework in my iOS application.
but, after following exact sequence as mentioned in their doc, i am seeing `error 403 Forbidden`

Is there anyone who tried Pytch SDK?

https://support.clickbank.com/entries/40354996-Pytch-SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. The error was in the id that i was passing. It was wrong, i corrected the id and it worked.